# Using join() to create a HTML id?

Tags: javascript

I have 6 Hidden fields which are to hold a latitude and longitude for 3 different postcodes:

```
<input type="hidden" id="geo_lat1" name="geo_lat1">
<input type="hidden" id="geo_lon1" name="geo_lon1">
<input type="hidden" id="geo_lat2" name="geo_lat2">
<input type="hidden" id="geo_lon2" name="geo_lon2">
<input type="hidden" id="geo_lat3" name="geo_lat3">
<input type="hidden" id="geo_lon3" name="geo_lon3">
```

I also have the three input fields for the postcodes:

```
<input type="text" name="search_postcode1" id="search_postcode1">
<input type="text" name="search_postcode2" id="search_postcode2">
<input type="text" name="search_postcode3" id="search_postcode3">
```

The geocoding function I have works fine, but only for the first set of lat/longs. If I want to produce the lat/longs for the other two postcodes, I would have to copy and paste the geocoding function for each postcode, just changing the number at the end of the input name in the following line:

```
var sAddress1 =document.getElementById("search_postcode1").value ;
```

Instead of copying/pasting I  want to use the same code but in a loop, which means changing the reference from search_postcode1 to search_postcode2 and search_postcode3

I know I can use join() to join data in an array and assign it to another variable like so:

```
var a = new Array("search_postcode","1");
var pcname = a.join(""); // pcname would be assigned "search_postcode1"
```

My question is how do I assign it so that it would appear in the line of code above rather than a value in a variable?

---

### EDIT

I also need to assign it to the hidden fields using:

```
geo_lat1.value = loc[0];
geo_lon1.value = loc[1];
```

How do I change the '1's in this to a '2' and a '3' in a loop? It must be a different way to the getElementById("search_postcode" + "1") way?

Comment: You can also use `"search_postcode" + "1"` (and the "1" can be in a variable).

Comment: what, use the code youve put in the getElementById? surely not that simple!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  var address = document.getElementById('search_postcode' + i);

  // Do something with address. Each time through the loop, it will
  //  reference the "i" search_postcode input, 1-3. Maybe something like:

  var loc = geoCodePostCode(address.value);

  document.getElementById('geo_lat' + i).value = loc[0];
  document.getElementById('geo_long' + i).value = loc[1];
}
```

Comment: bang on, thankyou! I didnt realise you could set values using getElementById, I thought it was only for getting!